# Autotools & Libtool - How to compile shared library from multiple source directories?

Tags: c++, autotools, automake, libtool, linkage

I'm trying to build a library from Autotools (Automake/Libtool)

My directory structure is :

```
src/MyLib/*some_sources*.cpp/.h + a Makefile.am
src/MyLib/Parsers/*some_other_sources.cpp/.h Makefile.am
```

When I put all my source files in the same directory (so, no "Parsers" subdir), allthing works fine. (compilation, then linkage from other programs)

But when I try my "ideal structure" (a base source folder + a "Parsers" subdir), I get a linkage error when I try to compile a program with the library :

```
<< usr/local/lib/mylib.so: undefined reference to <a function from "/Parsers" subdir > >>
```

It seems that Libtool doesn't link statically my subdir "Parsers" during compilation (maybe considering it as an external shared library ?)

Here is my base "Makefile.am" :

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = mylib.la
SUBDIRS = Parsers .
mylib_la_SOURCES = <base_dir_source_files>
```

And my "Makefile.am" in Parsers subdir :

```
mylib_la_SOURCES = <parsers_dir_source_files>
```

Of course, I libtoolize-d, autoreconf-ed allthing, after creating "Parser" subdir.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing in your case is simply not to add a `Makefile.am` file to the Parsers directory. Instead, add the source file names to `MyLib/Makefile.am` prefixed with `$(srcdir)/Parsers/` (better with a variable).

Something like this:

```
src/
|
\--MyLib/
   |
   |--Makefile.am
   |--base.cpp
   |--base.h
   \--Parsers/
      |
      |--parser.cpp
      \--parser.h
```

And in src/MyLib/Makefile.am:

```
PARSERS=$(srcdir)/Parsers
foo_SOURCES: base.cpp base.h \
    $(PARSERS)/parse.cpp $(PARSERS)/parse.h
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but I seems it's in conflicts with recursive Makefiles (I got errors because .o/.lo was created in topdir), so I just removed all subdirs MakefileS,  and created an unique Makefile which call all source files like "/MyVery/Long/Path/To/Source.cpp". It's ugly, but it works fine.

Comment: Oh, then try using the `$(srcdir)` variable. Or even `$(top_srcdir)/MyLib`. But with the full absolute path in `Makefile.am` your project is not relocatable, and that is not a good idea.

Comment: No, it's a relative Path, but the project structure is quite deep ;)

Comment: Add `subdir-objects` to your `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` call. You may also need to add additional macro calls like `AM_PROG_CC_C_O`.